# Jenkins build log has encoded URLs to child jobs/projects

Tags: jenkins, console-output

My Jenkins (1.539 on RHEL) job, named "**Parent-Job**", is configured to "**Trigger/call builds on other projects**"; the project triggered is named "**Child-Job**".

Jenkins "console output" shows the proper output (plain text with HTML links to the Child-Job that was triggered), as shown below:

```
Console Output

Started by user Rodin, A
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace /var/test/build/jendev_home/jobs/Parent-Job/workspace
No emails were triggered.
Waiting for the completion of Child-Job
Child-Job #44 completed. Result was SUCCESS
...
```

But in the **"log" file in the build** directory, the links that were present in the console output are all **encoded**, and I am unable to **parse these links** because the encoded text does not match expected value, as shown below:

```
Building on master in workspace /var/test/...
No emails were triggered.
Waiting for the completion of ESC[8mha:A..._very_long_encoded_value_...9M1g0N0AcApv0yfqQAAAA=ESC[0mChild-Job
...
```

How can I **extract the text of the console output, exactly in the same plain text/html format as is displayed on the Jenkins console**?

I need to email the log to various users, and long encoded links in the attachment will make them overlook other important details in the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the console output with the wget command (in a post build step script):

```
wget -O my_console.log ${BUILD_URL}consoleText
```

Comment: **Thanks! This worked.** Had to tweak it a little for the authentication etc. but in the end, the fact that the consoleText can directly be fetched using wget really helped!